# Creating xml document from a list<string> in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have a list "fetchXmlList" of strings which contains different fetch xmls. I want to create xml document using this list.

Xml document looks like:

```
<mappings>
 <main_fetchxml>
    fetchXmlList[0]
 </main_fetchxml>
 <relatedqueries>
    fetchXmlList[1]
    fetchXmlList[2]
         .
         .
         .
 </relatedqueries>
</mappings>
```

For relatedqueries xml node, I will have to add foreach loop and iterate over each list items starting from 2nd list item till the end of the list.

I started writing following lines of code:

```
 XmlDocument fetchXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 XmlElement rootNode = fetchXmlDoc.CreateElement("main_fetchxml");
 fetchXmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);
 rootNode.AppendChild(fetchXmlList[0]);
```

But appending list item to XmlElement object doesn't allow. Is there any other way?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Can edit your original question to include the code samples ? It is very hard to read code in comments.

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlDocument? If you can use LINQ to XML, this becomes trivial... although I would question your use of multiple values in a single element like that, using line breaks within a text node...

Comment: "But appending list item to XmlElement object doesn't allow. " What do you mean by that? Are you receiving an error? Compile-time or execution time? Please clarify.

Comment: you will need a root element, its not possible to have two xml root elements

Comment: Yes I am receiving compile time error "Argument type String is not assignable to parameter type System.Xml.XmlNode".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) you must have a root element

2) try this code

```
public static string Fetch2Xml(string s)
{      
    return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String s = "&lt;fetch distinct=\"false\" no-lock=\"false\" mapping=\"logical\" /&gt;";

    String[] sa = new string[] { s, s, s, s, s, s, s };

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    XmlElement someRoot = doc.CreateElement("mappings");

    XmlElement ele = doc.CreateElement("main_fetchxml");
    ele.InnerXml = Fetch2Xml(sa[0]);
    someRoot.AppendChild(ele);

    XmlElement ele2 = doc.CreateElement("relatedqueries");

    for (int a = 1; a < sa.Length; ++a)
    {
        ele2.InnerXml += Fetch2Xml(sa[a]);
    }

    someRoot.AppendChild(ele2);
    doc.AppendChild(someRoot);

    doc.Save(@"c:\temp\bla.xml");
}
```

that will lead too :

```
<mappings>
  <main_fetchxml>
    <fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" />
  </main_fetchxml>
  <relatedqueries>
    <fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" />
    <fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" />
    <fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" />
    <fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" />
    <fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" />
    <fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" />
  </relatedqueries>
</mappings>
```

Comment: and you may use a string builder ^^

Comment: Since fetchXmlList contains fetchxmls, above code will not add xml tags properly. 

Ex: 

&lt;fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical"&gt;&lt;

Also, all the list items should be properly formatted and form formatted xml document.

Comment: Pls just change InnerText to InnerXml in your previous answer. That worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: you will need the fetch2xml or you will get : <mappings>
  <main_fetchxml>
    <fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" />
  </main_fetchxml>
  <relatedqueries>&lt;fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" /&gt;&lt;fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" /&gt;&lt;fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" /&gt;&lt;fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" /&gt;&lt;fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" /&gt;&lt;fetch distinct="false" no-lock="false" mapping="logical" /&gt;</relatedqueries>
</m...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
public static void SerializeObject(this List<string> list, string fileName)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
        using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, list);
        }
    }

    public static void Deserialize(this List<string> list, string fileName)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            var other = (List<string>)(serializer.Deserialize(stream));
            list.Clear();
            list.AddRange(other);
        }
    }
```